# I have one test file and one train file for my prediction task do I need to preprocess also the test data exactly like the train data?

Tags: machine-learning, data-preprocessing

I have one test and one train csv file. Do I need to preprocess (e.g. fill nan values, use standard scaler etc) the train data and the test data simultaneously? Or should i first preprocess the train data ( e.g. fill nan values, use standard scaler etc) train the selected model and then apply those steps to the test data before finally testing the model?

I am still not sure about the right order of the steps.

Answer (score 0):

I always preprocess them separately and I think that is the better approach. Here's the pipeline I'd recommend:

1. Preprocess Training Data:

   - Fill missing values (NaN values).
   - Engineer features if needed.
   - Scale or normalize features.
   - Encode categorical variables (one-hot encoding…).
2. Train the Model:
   Train using preprocessed training data.
3. Preprocess Test Data:
   Use the same preprocessing as training data.
4. Test the Model:
   Evaluate with preprocessed test data.

When preprocessing is done together, information from the test data can unintentionally influence the preprocessing steps. This can lead to unreal good evaluation results during testing, as the model could have indirectly "seen" the test data through shared preprocessing.

For instance, consider if normalization is part of your preprocessing. Normalization involves transforming features so that they have a similar scale, which can be crucial for many ML algorithms. If you normalize the data using statistics from both the training and test sets together, you might inadvertently introduce information from the test set into the training process. This could lead to overly optimistic evaluations during testing and potentially harm the model's performance on new unseen data.

Remember, separate preprocessing simulates real-world situations better and prevents data leakage as discussed [here](https://www.kaggle.com/discussions/getting-started/308255). Good luck!